# Upper and lower bounds for $|L(1+it,\chi)|$ for complex primitive character $\chi$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I would guess this is some standard fact related to the zero-free region. But cannot find it in the textbooks I read.

Comment: Upper bound: Summation by parts. Lower bound: use the 3-4-1 inequality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, see Montgomery & Vaughan's "Multiplicative Number Theory", Theorem 11.3 and 11.4.  For example, in the zero free region of 11.3,
$$
\frac{1}{L(s,\chi)} \ll \log(q(|t|+4)).
$$